# Help with this .sh code

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to create a shell script that will change a file extenstion when you type something like this into the terminal:

extcha xx yy *.xx

This is the code I produced

```
#!/bin/sh

while [ *.$1 ] ; do

    export name=`basename $i .$1`
    echo mv $name.$1 $name.$2

done;
```

This doesn't seem to work. Can someone tell me where i'm going wrong?

Comment: don't you need to execute the command instead of just echoing it?

Comment: @Pablitorun, thanks for pointing that out. It still doesn't work though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renaming a file extension without specifying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068733/renaming-a-file-extension-without-specifying)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you mean to do:

```
for name in *.$1; do
    stripped_name="$(basename "$name" ".$1")"
    mv "$name.$1" "$name.$2"
done
```

The big flaw in yours is that the while loop just evaluates that condition, effectively testing for the existence of files with names of that form. It doesn't store anything in any variable - certainly not something arbitrary like `$i`. You also needn't export anything here. That just makes it visible to child processes, which you don't need.

Of course, you could really just use a rename utility. With the basic one (redhat and friends):

```
# Note that this will actually rename abc.foo.foo to abc.bar.foo
# since it replaces the first match.
rename .foo .bar *.foo
```

and with the fancy perl one (debian/ubuntu):

```
rename 's/.foo$/bar/' *.foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `rename` utility... It does this.

EDIT: The script.

```
#!/bin/bash

from="$1"
shift
to="$1"
shift

IFS="
"
for f in $@
do
  basefile="`basename "$f" ".$from"`"
  if [ ! "$basefile" = "$f" ]
  then
    echo mv "$basefile.$from" "$basefile.$to"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Do note that there are two different renames commonly distributed with Linux, a [fairly rudimentary one](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) doing simple string replacement, and [a more powerful one](http://man.he.net/man1/rename) using Perl regex. I believe the former is used in the redhat family, and the latter in the debian/ubuntu family - don't know about other distros.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is use a while state that will find all the xx extensions ($1) and change it into the yy extension ($2). Basically I want to excute this file with a while loop.

Comment: @Mr Teeth: Yes, but why? The rename utility can do this for you.

Comment: I've never heard of the rename utility. I'm just started using bash literally a month ago. Just trying to keep it simple that's all. Thanks for the code. I break it apart and study how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
for i in  *.$1 ; do


    name=`basename $i .$1`
    mv $name.$1 $name.$2

done
```

Don't forget to add some error checking (that there are two arguments for example)

Comment: This breaks if there's no files ending in $1, or if $1 contains spaces.

Comment: @Eric, which is probably why I suggested adding some error checking :(