# Renaming a file extension without specifying

Tags: bash, shell

I am creating a bash shell script that will rename a file extension without having to specify the old file extension name. If I enter "change foo *" to the Terminal in Linux, it will change all file extension to foo.

So lets say I've got four files: "file1.txt", "file2.txt.txt", "file3.txt.txt.txt" and "file4."

When I run the command, the files should look like this: "file1.foo", "file2.txt.foo", "file3.txt.txt.foo" and "file4.foo"

Can someone look at my code and correct it. I would also appreciate it if someone can implement this for me.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    shift

    ext=$1

    for file in "$@"
    do
        cut=`echo $FILE |sed -n '/^[a-Z0-9]*\./p'`
        if test "${cut}X" == 'X'; then
            new="$file.$ext"
        else
            new=`echo $file | sed "s/\(.*\)\..*/\1.$ext/"`
        fi
        mv $file $new
    done
    exit
```

Comment: What do you do with for example `important.files.tar.gz.gpg` (encrypted gzipped tar ball of important files)? Does it become `important.foo`, `important.files.foo`, `important.files.tar.foo`, `important.files.tar.gz.foo`, or `important.files.tar.gz.gpg.foo`?

Comment: It should become "important.files.tar.gz.foo".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Always use double quotes around variable substitutions, e.g. `echo "$FILE"` and not `echo $FILE`. Without double quotes, the shell expands whitespace and glob characters (`\[*?`) in the value of the variable. (There are cases where you don't need the quotes, and sometimes you do want word splitting, but that's for a future lesson.)
- I'm not sure what you're trying to do with sed, but whatever it is, I'm sure it's doable in the shell.

  - To check if `$FILE` contains a dot: `case "$FILE" in *.*) echo yes;; *) echo no;; esac`
  - To strip the last extension from `$FILE`: `${FILE%.*}`. For example, if `$FILE` is `file1.txt.foo`, this produces `file1.txt`. More generally, `${FILE%SOME_PATTERN}` expands to `$FILE` with a the shortest suffix matching `SOME_PATTERN` stripped off. If there is no matching suffix, it expands to `$FILE` unchanged. The variant `${FILE%%SOME_PATTERN}` strips the longest suffix. Similarly, `${FILE#SOME_PATTERN}` and `${FILE##SOME_PATTERN}` strip a suffix.
- `test "${TEMP}X" == 'X'` is weird. This looks like a misremembered trick from the old days. The normal way of writing this is `[ "$TEMP" = "" ]` or `[ -z "$TEMP" ]`. Using `==` instead of `=` is a bash extension. There used to be buggy shells that might parse the command incorrectly if `$TEMP` looked like an operator, but these have gone the way of the dinosaur, and even then, the `X` needs to be at the beginning, because the problematic operators begin with a `-`: `[ "X$TEMP" == "X" ]`.
- If a file name begins with a `-`, `mv` will think it's an option. Use `--` to say “that's it, no more options, whatever follows is an operand”: `mv -- "$FILE" "$NEW_FILE"`.
- This is very minor, but a common (not universal) convention is to use capital letters for environment variables and lowercase letters for internal script variables.
- Since you're using only standard shell features, you can start the script with `#!/bin/sh` (but `#!/bin/bash` works too, of course).
- `exit` at the end of the script is useless.

Applying all of these, here's the resulting script.

```
#!/bin/sh
ext="$1"; shift
for file in "$@"; do
  base="${file%.*}"
  mv -- "$file" "$base.$ext"
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gilles. This is very useful information! I need to edit my code according to what you have mentioned in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are asking about, but have a look at the perl `rename` utility. Very powerful! `man rename` is a good start.

Comment: Yeah, i'm aware of that, but i'm creating this code as part of an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Use: for file in *.gif; do mv $file ${file%.gif}.jpg; done

Or see [How to rename multiple files](http://its-cloudy.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-rename-multiple-file-extensions.html)

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked

```
for FILE in `ls`
do
NEW_FILE=${FILE%.*}
NEW_FILE=${NEW_FILE}${EXT}
done
```

I just want to tell about `NEW_FILE=${FILE%.*}`.
Here NEW_FILE gets the file name as output. You can use it as you want.
I tested in bash with `uname -a = "Linux 2.4.20-8smp #1 SMP Thu Mar 13 17:45:54 EST 2003 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux"`

Comment: Don't use `ls` like that. Use `for FILE in *` or it will fail if filename has spaces.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: **Actually its clearly mentioned what I wanted to share.** It was `I just want to tell about NEW_FILE=${FILE%.*}`. Rest of all is a piece of cake. I believe OP very much wanted this thing only. Otherwise he is using `for FILE in "$@"`

Comment: You are most welcome @Mr... Well I like your name Mr Teeth :-)