# find: paths must precede expression

Tags: bash, shell

I'm getting this error:

"find: paths must precede expression

Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]"

For this code I produced:

```
for subdir in `find ./$file/ -name "*.$@"`
do
new_ext=`echo $subdir | sed "s/\(.*\.\)$/\1$new/"`
mv $subfile $new_ext
done
```

What i'm trying to do with the code above is rename files extensions in current and sub-directories without having to enter the old file extension.

Any help pointing out what i'm doing wrong would be grateful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renaming a file extension without specifying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068733/renaming-a-file-extension-without-specifying)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt:

```
for old_extension in "$@"
do  
    find ./$file -name "*.$old_extension" | while read old_file
    do
        new_file=${old_file%$old_extension}new
        echo mv "$old_file" "$new_file"
    done
done
```

- The output of the find command is read by the while loop, one line at a time, each line is assigned to the variable $old_file
- The ${old_file%$old_extension} construct removes the extension, then the new extension 'new' is appended to $new_file
- The echo mv ... line will output to the screen the for visual verification
- Once you are happy with the result, you can remove the echo and run the script again to really do the damage. Remember: please check the result before removing the echo.
- Note that I have tested my solution against files with and without embedded spaces.

Comment: Yes, the original code is terrible for various reasons. But you've completely missed the point that *the `find` command doesn't work*.

Comment: @Ignacio: I have edited the code to take in account of multiple extensions. The find command should work now, provide that Mr. Teeth set the value for the *file* variable.

Answer (score 1):

`"*.$@"` surely doesn't do what you want. Build the command [in an array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: I was thinking should I just name it as "$@"? I read what you linked me. Thanks.

Comment: No. You still need multiple `-name` predicates (and `-o`, if you want it to work properly).